# A Record causes DNS issues

Tags: domain-name-system

We have two networks, able to talk via routes and DNS transfers.
lets call DomainA.local and DomainB.local

DomainB.Local
has a sever called FileServer (FQDN FileServer.DomainB.local)

In both Domains A and B we have Zones setup(DNS servers exchanging records between both domains), however because of an applicaton in DomainB, we need users in DomainA to access it.
However it wont work from DomainA to FileServer.DomainB.local
As the application is looking for "FileServer" not "FileServer.DomainB.Local" path.

So we thought setting up a Zone Record in DomainA to point to the IP in DomainB
So you would basically have FileServer.DomainA.local, (so the application

This turned out to be wrong and we removed the entry.
However when we come to folder browse from DomainA to \\FileServer.DomainB.local we get the following error

[image]

This use to work before we did the DNS change, its been several hours now since the record was removed however we are still getting the error,

What do we need to do to resolve this issue, (FYI browsing to other servers from DomainA to DomainB all seem to work fine)?

Comment: Two things: 1. The string you blacked out in that screenshot doesn't look long enough to be a FQDN. 2. Obfuscating your internal server names really doesn't do anything. Your internal server names don't mean anything to us. It's not a "security" risk to let us know the actual server names.

Comment: 1.it is a fqdn, just think of it as \\FileServer.DomainB.local, 2.you get the idea, and dont need the real names as its been documented above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we had a External trust in place between the two domains, it turned out that although users from Domain A could access files on Domain B, we ended up repairing\validating the trust, and bingo! it all worked!

Hope this helps anyone else out with such a strange behaviour!